# Header-only C++ library (GLM) doesn't compile with Android-NDK

Tags: c++, stl, android-ndk, android-stlport

I want to use the GLM ([glm.g-truc.net](http://glm.g-truc.net/)) header-only C++ library in an Android NDK project, but I get compile errors. In the `Android.mk`, I've added the header search path

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/
```

and I've also tried to compile using STLport and GNU-STL by setting the following in `Application.mk` like described in the CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT document:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

or

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

respectively. Nothing helps; Those are the errors I get when including `<glm/glm.h>` and using an `glm::ivec2`. `ndk-build` outputs:

```
Compile++ arm    : wbar <= QCARBase.cpp
In file included from /Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/glm.hpp:66,
                 from /Users/Johannes/proj/WirtschaftsblattAR/app/android/wbar/jni/QCARBase.cpp:45:
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.hpp:240: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.hpp:240: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.hpp:240: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.hpp:251: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.hpp:251: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.hpp:251: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
In file included from /Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.hpp:335,
                 from /Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/glm.hpp:66,
                 from /Users/Johannes/proj/WirtschaftsblattAR/app/android/wbar/jni/QCARBase.cpp:45:
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1202: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1202: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1202: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1217: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1217: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1217: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1228: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1228: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1228: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1240: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1240: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1240: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1253: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1253: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1253: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1268: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1268: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1268: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1279: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1279: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1279: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1291: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1291: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
/Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/glm/./core/func_common.inl:1291: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
make: *** [/Users/Johannes/proj/WirtschaftsblattAR/app/android/wbar/obj/local/armeabi/objs/wbar/QCARBase.o] Error 1
```

I'm using the Crystax NDK r6 ([www.crystax.net](http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk/6))

Comment: Have you tried `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/Johannes/Development/glm_include/` instead of LOCAL_CFLAGS?

Comment: Yes, this has the same effect. The compiler obviously finds the files, because the above errors are in the included files.

Comment: show code before including glm/glm.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I've managed to compile it. Specifying the following options in the `Application.mk` did the trick:

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_STL := stlport_static
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := thumb
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

And, I think with the STLport, you can't use RTTI or Exceptions, so don't enable `-frtti` or `-fexceptions` in the `Android.mk`

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of header hopping, I figured out how to fix this with the GNU libstdc++ runtime.

Try defining `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH` to 1 before including `<glm.hpp>`, like this:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH 1
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

`<glm.hpp>` includes `<cmath>`, which in turn includes `<math.h>`.  The `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH` macro forces `<cmath>` to `#undef` some macros from `<math.h>` which would otherwise hide some `glm` functions like `isnan()`, `isinf()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try building a small sample test app like this:

```
#include <glm/glm.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Does that work?

If it does, then I'm going to bet that in your app, you have your glm.h include after some #define that has a symbol collision with a symbol that is used in glm. Your #define is probably making use of the sizeof keyword and that is being substituted in the glm lines that have errors.

A possible solution would be to move the glm.h include above any other #includes and/or #defines, if you make it the first thing in the file you may bypass the problem.

A better solution would be to try to avoid #defines and use inline functions whenever possible.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried that - including only `<glm/glm.hpp>`, but i keep getting the same errors. Could it be a compiler issue? It seems to have no effect, changing the STL library.

Comment: I've tested GLM on 2.3+(target API-10) in NDK application (r5c and r6b) and it worked just fine. Maybe Crystax is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue when I try to compile `glm` against `gnustl_static`, but I don't have any issues when I try to compile with `stlport_static`. My only suggestion would be to try declaring an `stlport` dependency using `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` in your shared library module.

Also, have you tried using `stlport_shared`? `stlport` has both shared and static libraries, whereas `gnustl` only has a static version (but supports exceptions/RTTI).